# win32 excel copy except function

Tags: python, excel, winapi, win32com

I use win32com in python for excel control and facing a little problem.

I want to copy my Excel Cell (1,1) i.e.B2 to "A1"

[image: Excel Worksheet]

Below is my code

```
Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(1,1), Sheet.Cells(LastRow, Lastcol)).copy(Sheet1.Range("A1"))
```

It works OK, but it copies the formula not the formula value (result).
( I want "0" not a "=SUM(C1,C2)" )

Please guide, how should I change my code to get desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be happening due to incorrect format of the destination cell. Hence, your code needs to be changed to below. I suggest that replace your exisiting given line with below:

```
'Change the format of cell to General as Text fields do not evaluate the formula
Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(1,1), Sheet.Cells(LastRow, Lastcol)).NumberFormat = "General"

'Copy the formula and assign it as formula (rather than copying it)
Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(1,1), Sheet.Cells(LastRow, Lastcol)).Formula  = Sheet1.Range("A1").Formula
```

Hope it helps !